# Записать данные из json в динамически создаваемые элементы без jQuery

Tags: javascript

Как записать данные из json по url в динамически создаваемые элементы?

Данные должны загружатся из внешнего сервера на страницу, в динамически создаваемые input. Сейчас реализовано через `alert`.
Вот код:

```
<div id="contacts_list"></div>

var module_contacts_list = (function() {   
 function ajax(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200)
     callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
   }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
 }
 ajax('http://', function(data){
  /*alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
  var contacts_list = document.getElementById('contacts_list'),
      list = '<input type="text" class="input">';
 });
})();
```

Полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/768v0zfy/)

Лучше всетаки записывать в `div`

разметка будет такая (формируется в js):

```
Лучше все таки записывать в `div`
```

разметка будет такая (формируется в js) [разметка](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/768v0zfy/1/)

Comment: _Сейчас реализовано через alert._ - тот который закомментирован?

Comment: _data_ приходит массивом, что именно вы хотите выводит в input, или в input'ах?

Comment: да с этой строкой `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` все загружается

Comment: в `input` я хочу выводить все пункты из json. там книга контактов

Comment: приведите пример разметки, которая в итоге должна получиться, а так же пример _data_

Comment: в выводимых элементах полями могут быть массивы, сложные объекты - как вы их хотите выводить?

Comment: в перспективе нужно будет сделать возможность редактирования. сейчас хотя бы просто пусть выводится хоть что-нибудь, чтобы понимать как это работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать свойство [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) для вставки содержимого

```js
var module_contacts_list = (function() {

  function ajax(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200)
          callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function(data) {
    /*alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
    var contacts_list = document.getElementById('contacts_list');

    contacts_list.innerHTML = data.map(function(el){
      return `<div data-name="${el.name}">${
        JSON.stringify(el)
      }</div>`;
    }).join('');

  });

})();
```

```html
<div id="contacts_list"></div>
```

Comment: тут нет jQuery? почему-то моя IDE выдает ошибку...

Comment: @MarinaVoronova нет, тут нет JQuery, но тут есть [ES6 String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) - это часть где собирается строка внутри функции `map`. Скорее всего не нее и ругается, так как ваша IDE может не поддерживать новый стандарт. Можете просто заменить ее собираем обычной строки

Comment: "Можете просто заменить ее собираем обычной строки" - как?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, например: `return "<div name='"+el.name+"'>"+JSON.stringify(el)+"</div>"`

Comment: а почему не так `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)`?

Comment: @Stack, в данном случае не принципиально

Comment: _"в данном случае не принципиально"_ -- согласен, просто вместо 4-х строк будет 2-е.